# Adding onclick and additional code to a .js document

Tags: javascript, onclick, cross-domain

I have a pretty specific question.  I am trying to implement an onclick and cross domain tracking within a block of text, but it looks like it may need to be put directly into a .js document.  I don't have a lot of JS experience.  Basically, the current code looks like:

```
// JavaScript Document
function popup_no_status(loc)
{
var windowW=1000
var windowH=700
s = "width="+windowW+",height="+windowH+",status=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes";
mywin = window.open(loc ,'CBE', s);
mywin.focus();
}
```

What I want to add to this is:

```
onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Button', 'Click', 'QuickSearchWidget'); pageTracker._link(this.href); return false;
```

Can I just add it to the end of the document before the closing bracket?  Any Ideas?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the object `pageTracker` is defined and instantiated, you can call its methods like any other function:

```
function popup_no_status(loc) {
    var s = "width=700,height=1000,status=yes, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes";
    var mywin = window.open(loc ,'CBE', s);
    mywin.focus();

    pageTracker._trackEvent('Button', 'Click', 'QuickSearchWidget');
    pageTracker._link(this.href);
}
```

Also, the variables `windowW` and `windowH` are pointless in your example code - there is no need to store the string values in a variable if all you're going to do is concatenate them into another string. Further, unless you intend the `mywin` and `s` variables to be global, you should use the `var` keyword before defining them - that restricts the variables to the function scope instead of the global scope (all variables declared in a function without the `var` keyword are considered global).

If the code above gives an error like `ReferenceError: pageTracker is not defined`, that means that the code in which the `pageTracker` object is defined is either not included on the page, or it has not been instantiated.

Now... as for onClick, I am not clear what you're after here. Do you want this function to run when someone clicks the document? That would get pretty annoying!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Chris!  Basically for the onclick command, I want to capture this in Google Analytics, so I want it to fire information back to GA when the user clicks on it.  Will the code above fire back to GA on the click?  Basically, this document is set up as a link <a href="AboveDocument.js;"></a>.

Does that make sense?

Comment: No - this code won't fire unless it is called. I don't think you mean that a popup should open every time something is clicked, and I guess I don't get what you're trying to do.